# ITMS - 90209 Invalid Segment Alignment

Tags: ios, flash, app-store, application-loader

I've updated XCode and still get this same error. I've installed adobe air 17 beta and adobe air SDK too.

ERROR ITMS - 90209 Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'Meteor Crash.app/Meteor Crash' does not have a proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, which is solved now. I was building with old flex SDK that is why it was throwing this error.

I downloaded flex 4.14 SDK with AIR 16.0 version using 'Apache FLEX SDK Installer'. And also you need to build the app using 64-bit supporting system. It solved my problem. And try to download from Installer. Hope this helps.